# End to end test suite can't retrieve env variables in Github Actions, but works fine in local

Tags: node.js, yaml, environment-variables, nestjs, github-actions

I am trying to set an environnement variable in Github Actions. It seems to be setup fine as I can display it using echo. Yet, my end-to-end suite doesn't run because:

`EnvVarError: env-var: "JWT_SECRET" is a required variable, but it was not set`

Which is a nice message displayed by a package I am recently using: [env-var](https://www.npmjs.com/package/env-var)
(might be related)

[image]

*The JWT secret is knowingly hardcoded and shared. I am going step by step, it will finally be removed and changed. It's in use for a pet side-project at the moment.*

As we can see, github actions can set and display the env var. But can't make it available for the test suite.

Here is the workflow:

```
name: Tests

on:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ master ]

jobs:

  backend-tests:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    defaults:
      run:
        working-directory: back
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
      uses: actions/setup-node@v2
      with:
        node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
        cache: 'yarn'
        cache-dependency-path: '**/back/yarn.lock'
    - run: sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start
    - run: mysql -e 'CREATE DATABASE corposano' -uroot -proot
    - run: mysql -e 'ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY ""' -uroot -proot
    - run: yarn
    - run: yarn build
    - run: yarn jest
    - run: yarn test:inte
      env:
        JWT_SECRET: MIIBO...
    - run: |
        JWT_SECRET=MIIBO...
        echo The JWT secret is:$JWT_SECRET
        yarn test:e2e
```

What did I miss to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it should be:

```yaml
    - run: |
        export JWT_SECRET=MIIBO...
        echo The JWT secret is:$JWT_SECRET
        yarn test:e2e
```

or

```yaml
    - run: |
        echo The JWT secret is:$JWT_SECRET
        yarn test:e2e
      env:
        JWT_SECRET: MIIBO...
```

Comment: `export ...` was indeed the trick needed to be done. Thanks!

Comment: A more proper way seems to move the `env : JWT_SECRET: MIIBO...` lines at the job level